In Power Apps, is there a way to use the PATCH function for updating time in a hh:mm AM/PM format?
I'm trying to create a Power App for updating the hours of operations for a business. The app is connected to an excel sheet on Onedrive. Things seemed to be coming along very well until I tried to actually push the patch through. I keep getting an error saying

The formula I'm using for the Patch is
UpdateIf(colData,true,{'Display Start Time':DateAdd(Text(DrpStartTimeHour.Selected.Value & 
":" & DrpStartTimeMinute.Selected.Value & " " & 
DrpStartTimeAMPM.Selected.Value),"h:mm AM/PM"),'Display End Time':DateAdd(Text(DrpEndTimeHour.Selected.Value 
& ":" & 
DrpEndTimeMinute.Selected.Value 
& " " &
DrpEndTimeAMPM.Selected.Value),"h:mm AM/PM"),
'Start DOW': Text(drpStartDOW.Selected.Value),
'End DOW': Text(drpEndDOW.Selected.Value),'Start Date':DateAdd(Text(drpStartDateSelect.Selected.Value),"mm/dd/yyyy"),
'End Date':DateAdd(Text(drpEndDateSelect.Selected.Value),"mm/dd/yyyy"),'Message Text':Text(MessageInput.Text)}); 
Patch(Table1,colData)

The application looks like this so far and requires being able to select different times and minutes and pushing it through to whatever locations are checked off. Is anyone able to help me optimize this formula?

